# Search an OPTION in a SELECT tag

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a beginner to intermediate web-dev knowledge, and I am doing a web-page that asks people some personal data.
It's an informal research about unemployment.
This is where I am hosting the [page](http://kelvin.byethost10.com/) (it is in Brazilian Portuguese).

I've got an occupation list from the "Ministry of Jobs" website, and I am showing this list in an SELECT field this way:

```
<?php
    $ocupacoes = file('ocupacoes');
    $options = '<option selected disabled>Selecione uma ocupação</option>';
    foreach ($ocupacoes as $ocupacao) {
        $options .= '<option value="'.$ocupacao.'">'.$ocupacao.'</option>';
    }
    $select = '<select id="ocupacoes" name="ocupacao">'.$options.'</select>';

    echo $select;
?>
```

Now this is what I want:

People be able to search their occupation easily, especially because people often access websites via their smartphones (searching an option in a list with hundreds of options in a smartphone is painful).

I tried doing this with `Select2` and `Selectize`, but with no success.
Maybe because I tried using it after a php code, I don't know.
I've found the `datalist` tag but I don't want to use it because people must select the predefined entries.
I've found that JQuery UI could help, but I don't know how to do it.

I need some help/light because I can't figure it out on my own.

I am accepting some tips too, about web-dev and/or my code, since the page is linked.

---

EDIT: JQuery wasn't defined. So **the answer is I had to rearrange the file's imports so JQuery was first imported, just then select2 could be imported**.
Thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/users/3367974/mehdi-dehghani for helping me find it out through console viewer.

Comment: You was in right way, using `jQuery plugin` like `select2` and `selectize` is best option. I'm using both of them in almost all of my projects, head to their websites to learn how to use them. (for ex. for `select2`, you just need to write this: `$('select').select2();`, easy enough, right?)

Comment: @MehdiDehghani I tried using this "constructor", but it just didn't work :(
Maybe I was using it wrong. I will try it in a fresh new file

Comment: It worked in a blank file, but tried the same way in the original page and didn't worked again... I think some css is messing select2. EDIT: definitely not css. maybe it do not recognize the php generated code

Comment: I'm afraid but I'm not PHP guy, but make sure you have not any js error, also try `console.log($('select'))`, it should log `select` correctly. if so, try to log `typeof $.fn.select2`, it should not be `undefined`

Comment: @mehdi damn how could I forget such an useful tool... console.log showed "Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined at select2.min.js:1", and I've already fixed it up. working now, gonna upload to server. thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to rearrange the file's imports so JQuery was first imported, just then select2 could be imported.

Thanks to [Mehdi Dehgani](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3367974/mehdi-dehghani) for helping find the answer via the console log.

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Projeto 02 - Desenvolvimento WEB</title>

    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://kelvin.96.lt/centralizaDivs.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://kelvin.96.lt/style.css">

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://kelvin.96.lt/validadores.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/css/select2.min.css" />
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.min.js"></script>

  </head>
<body>

<div id="outer">
    <div id="middle">
        <div id="inner">
            <legend id="formul">Formulário de pesquisa sobre desemprego</legend>
            <form name="cadastro" action="index.php" method="post" onsubmit="return validaForm()">
                <fieldset id="desemp">
                    <legend>Está desempregado?</legend>
                    <input type="radio" name="desempregado" value=1 id="d_sim" onclick="return validaOcupac()">
                    <label for="d_sim">Sim</label><br>
                    <input type="radio" name="desempregado" value=0 id="d_nao" onclick="return validaOcupac()">
                    <label for="d_nao">Não</label>
                </fieldset>
                <fieldset id="sex">
                    <legend>Selecione seu sexo</legend>
                    <input type="radio" name="sexo" value="Masculino" id="s_masculino">
                    <label for="s_masculino">Masculino</label><br>
                    <input type="radio" name="sexo" value="Feminino" id="s_feminino">
                    <label for="s_feminino">Feminino</label><br>
                    <input type="radio" name="sexo" value="Outros" id="s_outros">
                    <label for="s_outros">Outros</label>
                </fieldset>
                <fieldset>
                    <legend>Selecione seu nível de escolaridade</legend>
                    <select name="escolaridade">
                        <option selected disabled>Selecione o nível</option>
                        <option>Fundamental</option>
                        <option>Médio</option>
                        <option>Superior</option>
                        <option>Pós graduação</option>
                    </select><br>
                    <select name="emcurso">
                        <option selected disabled>-------------</option>
                        <option>Completo</option>
                        <option>Incompleto</option>
                        <option>Cursando</option>
                    </select>
                </fieldset>
                <fieldset>
                    <legend>De onde você é?</legend>
                    <select id="estados" name="estado">
                    </select><br>
                    <select id="cidades" name="cidade">
                    </select>
                </fieldset>
                <fieldset>
                    <legend>Idade</legend>
                    <input type="number" placeholder="Quantos anos você tem?" id="i_idade" name="idade">
                </fieldset>
                <fieldset>
                    <legend>Ocupação</legend>
                    <select id="ocupacoes" name="ocupacao">
                      <option selected disabled>Selecione uma ocupação</option><option value="Abatedor">Abatedor</option><option value="Acabador de calçados">Acabador de calçados</option>
                      <option value="Acabador de embalagens (flexíveis e cartotécnicas)">Acabador de embalagens (flexíveis e cartotécnicas)</option>
                  </select>             
                </fieldset>
                <div id="botoes">
                    <input type="submit"> <input type="reset">
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {

            $("#ocupacoes").select2();
            $.getJSON('estados_cidades.json', function (data) {
                var items = [];
                var options = '<option selected disabled>Selecione seu estado</option>';
                $.each(data, function (key, val) {
                    options += '<option value="' + val.nome + '">' + val.nome + '</option>';
                });
                $("#estados").html(options);
                $("#estados").change(function () {
                    var options_cidades = '';
                    var str = "";
                    $("#estados option:selected").each(function () {
                        str += $(this).text();
                    });
                    $.each(data, function (key, val) {
                        if(val.nome == str) {
                            $.each(val.cidades, function (key_city, val_city) {
                                options_cidades += '<option value="' + val_city + '">' + val_city + '</option>';
                            });
                        }
                    });
                    $("#cidades").html(options_cidades);
                }).change();
            });

        });
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using select2 will fix your issue, 
just import jquery + the CSS + JS select2 and write the script that render the input as below :

```
$(function(){

  $("#ocupacoes").select2();

});
```

See below working snipet :

```js
$(function(){

  $("#ocupacoes").select2();
  
});
```

```css
#ocupacoes {
  width:80%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/css/select2.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<select id="ocupacoes" name="ocupacao">
<option selected="" disabled="">Selecione uma ocupação</option><option value="Abatedor
">Abatedor
</option><option value="Acabador de calçados
">Acabador de calçados
</option><option value="Acabador de embalagens (flexíveis e cartotécnicas)
">Acabador de embalagens (flexíveis e cartotécnicas)
</option><option value="Acabador de superfícies de concreto
">Acabador de superfícies de concreto
</option><option value="Açougueiro
">Açougueiro
</option><option value="Acrobata
">Acrobata
</option><option value="Adestrador de animais
">Adestrador de animais
</option><option value="Administrador
">Administrador
</option><option value="Administrador de banco de dados
">Administrador de banco de dados
</option><option value="Operador de bomba de concreto
">Operador de bomba de concreto
</option><option value="Operador de branqueador de pasta para fabricação de papel
">Operador de branqueador de pasta para fabricação de papel
</option><option value="Operador de britadeira (tratamentos químicos e afins)
">Operador de britadeira (tratamentos químicos e afins)
</option><option value="Operador de britador de coque
">Operador de britador de coque
</option><option value="Operador de britador de mandíbulas
">Operador de britador de mandíbulas
</option><option value="Operador de cabine de laminação (fio-máquina)
">Operador de cabine de laminação (fio-máquina)
</option><option value="Operador de caixa
">Operador de caixa
</option><option value="Operador de calandra (química, petroquímica e afins)
">Operador de calandra (química, petroquímica e afins)
</option><option value="Operador de calandras (tecidos)
">Operador de calandras (tecidos)
</option><option value="Operador de calcinação (tratamento químico e afins)
">Operador de calcinação (tratamento químico e afins)
</option><option value="Operador de caldeira
">Operador de caldeira
</option><option value="Operador de câmaras frias
">Operador de câmaras frias
</option><option value="Operador de câmera de televisão
">Operador de câmera de televisão
</option><option value="Operador de caminhão (minas e pedreiras)
">Operador de caminhão (minas e pedreiras)
</option><option value="Operador de cardas
">Operador de cardas
</option><option value="Operador de carregadeira
">Operador de carregadeira
</option><option value="Operador de carro de apagamento e coque
">Operador de carro de apagamento e coque
</option><option value="Operador de ceifadeira na conservação de vias permanentes
">Operador de ceifadeira na conservação de vias permanentes
</option><option value="Operador de central de concreto
">Operador de central de concreto
</option><option value="Operador de central de rádio
">Operador de central de rádio
</option><option value="Operador de central hidrelétrica
">Operador de central hidrelétrica
</option><option value="Operador de central termoelétrica
">Operador de central termoelétrica
</option><option value="Operador de centrifugadora (tratamentos químicos e afins)
">Operador de centrifugadora (tratamentos químicos e afins)
</option><option value="Operador de centro de controle
">Operador de centro de controle
</option><option value="Operador de centro de controle (ferrovia e metrô)
">Operador de centro de controle (ferrovia e metrô)
</option><option value="Operador de centro de usinagem com comando numérico
">Operador de centro de usinagem com comando numérico
</option><option value="Operador de centro de usinagem de madeira (cnc)
">Operador de centro de usinagem de madeira (cnc)
</option><option value="Operador de chamuscadeira de tecidos
">Operador de chamuscadeira de tecidos
</option><option value="Operador de cobrança bancária
">Operador de cobrança bancária
</option><option value="Operador de colhedor florestal
">Operador de colhedor florestal
</option><option value="Operador de colheitadeira
">Operador de colheitadeira
</option><option value="Operador de compactadora de solos
">Operador de compactadora de solos
</option><option value="Operador de compressor de ar
">Operador de compressor de ar
</option><option value="Operador de computador (inclusive microcomputador)
">Operador de computador (inclusive microcomputador)
</option><option value="Operador de concentração
">Operador de concentração
</option><option value="Operador de conicaleira
">Operador de conicaleira
</option><option value="Operador de cortadeira de papel
">Operador de cortadeira de papel
</option><option value="Operador de cristalização na refinação de açucar
">Operador de cristalização na refinação de açucar
</option><option value="Operador de desempenadeira na usinagem convencional de madeira
">Operador de desempenadeira na usinagem convencional de madeira
</option><option value="Operador de desgaseificação
">Operador de desgaseificação
</option><option value="Operador de destilação e subprodutos de coque
">Operador de destilação e subprodutos de coque
</option><option value="Operador de digestor de pasta para fabricação de papel
">Operador de digestor de pasta para fabricação de papel
</option><option value="Operador de docagem
">Operador de docagem
</option><option value="Operador de draga
">Operador de draga
</option><option value="Operador de empilhadeira
">Operador de empilhadeira
</option><option value="Operador de enfornamento e desenfornamento de coque
">Operador de enfornamento e desenfornamento de coque
</option><option value="Operador de engomadeira de urdume
">Operador de engomadeira de urdume
</option><option value="Operador de entalhadeira (usinagem de madeira)
">Operador de entalhadeira (usinagem de madeira)
</option><option value="Operador de equipamento de destilação de álcool
">Operador de equipamento de destilação de álcool
</option><option value="Operador de equipamento de secagem de pintura
">Operador de equipamento de secagem de pintura
</option><option value="Operador de equipamento para resfriamento
">Operador de equipamento para resfriamento
</option><option value="Operador de equipamentos de preparação de areia
">Operador de equipamentos de preparação de areia
</option><option value="Operador de equipamentos de refinação de açúcar (processo contínuo)
">Operador de equipamentos de refinação de açúcar (processo contínuo)
</option><option value="Operador de escavadeira
">Operador de escavadeira
</option><option value="Operador de escória e sucata
">Operador de escória e sucata
</option><option value="Operador de esmaltadeira
">Operador de esmaltadeira
</option><option value="Operador de espelhamento
">Operador de espelhamento
</option><option value="Operador de espessador
">Operador de espessador
</option><option value="Operador de espuladeira
">Operador de espuladeira
</option><option value="Operador de estação de bombeamento
">Operador de estação de bombeamento
</option><option value="Operador de estação de captação, tratamento e distribuição de água
">Operador de estação de captação, tratamento e distribuição de água
</option><option value="Operador de estação de tratamento de água e efluentes
">Operador de estação de tratamento de água e efluentes
</option><option value="Operador de evaporador na destilação
">Operador de evaporador na destilação
</option><option value="Operador de exaustor (coqueria)
">Operador de exaustor (coqueria)
</option><option value="Operador de exploração de petróleo
">Operador de exploração de petróleo
</option><option value="Operador de externa (rádio)
">Operador de externa (rádio)
</option><option value="Operador de extração de café solúvel
">Operador de extração de café solúvel
</option><option value="Operador de extrusora (química, petroquímica e afins)
">Operador de extrusora (química, petroquímica e afins)
</option><option value="Pesquisador de engenharia metalúrgica, de minas e de materiais
">Pesquisador de engenharia metalúrgica, de minas e de materiais
</option><option value="Pesquisador de engenharia química
">Pesquisador de engenharia química
</option><option value="Pesquisador de medicina básica
">Pesquisador de medicina básica
</option><option value="Pesquisador em biologia ambiental
">Pesquisador em biologia ambiental
</option><option value="Pesquisador em biologia animal
">Pesquisador em biologia animal
</option><option value="Pesquisador em biologia de microorganismos e parasitas
">Pesquisador em biologia de microorganismos e parasitas
</option><option value="Pesquisador em biologia humana
">Pesquisador em biologia humana
</option><option value="Pesquisador em biologia vegetal
">Pesquisador em biologia vegetal
</option><option value="Pesquisador em ciências agronômicas
">Pesquisador em ciências agronômicas
</option><option value="Pesquisador em ciências da computação e informática
">Pesquisador em ciências da computação e informática
</option><option value="Pesquisador em ciências da educação
">Pesquisador em ciências da educação
</option><option value="Pesquisador em ciências da pesca e aqüicultura
">Pesquisador em ciências da pesca e aqüicultura
</option><option value="Pesquisador em ciências da terra e meio ambiente
">Pesquisador em ciências da terra e meio ambiente
</option><option value="Pesquisador em ciências da zootecnia
">Pesquisador em ciências da zootecnia
</option><option value="Pesquisador em ciências florestais
">Pesquisador em ciências florestais
</option><option value="Publicitário
">Publicitário
</option><option value="Pugilista
">Pugilista
</option><option value="Queijeiro na fabricação de laticínio
">Queijeiro na fabricação de laticínio
</option><option value="Químico
">Químico
</option><option value="Químico industrial
">Químico industrial
</option><option value="Quiropraxista
">Quiropraxista
</option><option value="Rachador de couros e peles
">Rachador de couros e peles
</option><option value="Radiotelegrafista
">Radiotelegrafista
</option><option value="Raizeiro
">Raizeiro
</option><option value="Rebaixador de couros
">Rebaixador de couros
</option><option value="Rebarbador de metal
">Rebarbador de metal
</option><option value="Rebitador a  martelo pneumático
">Rebitador a  martelo pneumático
</option><option value="Rebitador, a  mão
">Rebitador, a  mão
</option><option value="Recebedor de apostas (loteria)
">Recebedor de apostas (loteria)
</option><option value="Recebedor de apostas (turfe)
">Recebedor de apostas (turfe)
</option><option value="Recepcionista de banco
">Recepcionista de banco
</option><option value="Recepcionista de casas de espetáculos
">Recepcionista de casas de espetáculos
</option><option value="Recepcionista de consultório médico ou dentário
">Recepcionista de consultório médico ou dentário
</option><option value="Recepcionista de hotel
">Recepcionista de hotel
</option><option value="Recepcionista de seguro saúde
">Recepcionista de seguro saúde
</option><option value="Recepcionista, em geral
">Recepcionista, em geral
</option><option value="Recreador
">Recreador
</option><option value="Recreador de acantonamento
">Recreador de acantonamento
</option><option value="Recuperador de guias e cilindros
">Recuperador de guias e cilindros
</option><option value="Redator de publicidade
">Redator de publicidade
</option><option value="Redator de textos técnicos
">Redator de textos técnicos
</option><option value="Redeiro
">Redeiro
</option><option value="Redeiro (pesca)
">Redeiro (pesca)
</option><option value="Refinador de óleo e gordura
">Refinador de óleo e gordura
</option><option value="Refinador de sal
">Refinador de sal
</option><option value="Relações públicas
">Relações públicas
</option><option value="Relojoeiro (fabricação)
">Relojoeiro (fabricação)
</option><option value="Relojoeiro (reparação)
">Relojoeiro (reparação)
</option><option value="Remetedor de fios
">Remetedor de fios
</option><option value="Reparador de aparelhos de telecomunicações em laboratório
">Reparador de aparelhos de telecomunicações em laboratório
</option><option value="Reparador de aparelhos eletrodomésticos (exceto imagem e som)
">Reparador de aparelhos eletrodomésticos (exceto imagem e som)
</option><option value="Reparador de equipamentos de escritório
">Reparador de equipamentos de escritório
</option><option value="Reparador de equipamentos fotográficos
">Reparador de equipamentos fotográficos
</option><option value="Reparador de instrumentos musicais
">Reparador de instrumentos musicais
</option><option value="Reparador de rádio, tv e som
">Reparador de rádio, tv e som
</option><option value="Repórter (exclusive rádio e televisão)
">Repórter (exclusive rádio e televisão)
</option><option value="Repórter de rádio e televisão
">Repórter de rádio e televisão
</option><option value="Repórter fotográfico
">Repórter fotográfico
</option><option value="Repositor de mercadorias
">Repositor de mercadorias
</option><option value="Representante comercial autônomo
">Representante comercial autônomo
</option><option value="Restaurador de instrumentos musicais (exceto cordas arcadas)
">Restaurador de instrumentos musicais (exceto cordas arcadas)
</option><option value="Restaurador de livros
">Restaurador de livros
</option><option value="Retalhador de carne
">Retalhador de carne
</option><option value="Revelador de filmes fotográficos, em cores
">Revelador de filmes fotográficos, em cores
</option><option value="Revelador de filmes fotográficos, em preto e branco
">Revelador de filmes fotográficos, em preto e branco
</option><option value="Revestidor de interiores (papel, material plástico e emborrachados)
">Revestidor de interiores (papel, material plástico e emborrachados)
</option><option value="Revestidor de superfícies de concreto
">Revestidor de superfícies de concreto
</option><option value="Revisor de fios (produção têxtil)
">Revisor de fios (produção têxtil)
</option><option value="Revisor de tecidos acabados
">Revisor de tecidos acabados
</option><option value="Revisor de tecidos crus
">Revisor de tecidos crus
</option><option value="Revisor de texto
">Revisor de texto
</option><option value="Riscador de estruturas metálicas
">Riscador de estruturas metálicas
</option><option value="Riscador de roupas
">Riscador de roupas
</option><option value="Sacristão
">Sacristão
</option><option value="Salgador de alimentos
">Salgador de alimentos
</option><option value="Salsicheiro (fabricação de lingüiça, salsicha e produtos similares)
">Salsicheiro (fabricação de lingüiça, salsicha e produtos similares)
</option><option value="Salva-vidas
">Salva-vidas
</option><option value="Sanitarista
">Sanitarista
</option><option value="Sapateiro (calçados sob medida)
">Sapateiro (calçados sob medida)
</option><option value="Sargento bombeiro militar
">Sargento bombeiro militar
</option><option value="Sargento da policia militar
">Sargento da policia militar
</option><option value="Secador de madeira
">Secador de madeira
</option><option value="Secretária trilíngüe
">Secretária trilíngüe
</option><option value="Secretária(o) executiva(o)
">Secretária(o) executiva(o)
</option><option value="Secretário  bilíngüe
">Secretário  bilíngüe
</option><option value="Secretário - executivo
">Secretário - executivo
</option><option value="Segundo oficial de máquinas da marinha mercante
">Segundo oficial de máquinas da marinha mercante
</option><option value="Segundo tenente de polícia militar
">Segundo tenente de polícia militar
</option><option value="Selecionador de material reciclável
">Selecionador de material reciclável
</option><option value="Seleiro
">Seleiro
</option><option value="Senador
">Senador
</option><option value="Sepultador
">Sepultador
</option><option value="Sericultor
">Sericultor
</option><option value="Seringueiro
">Seringueiro
</option><option value="Serrador de bordas no desdobramento de madeira
">Serrador de bordas no desdobramento de madeira
</option><option value="Serrador de madeira
">Serrador de madeira
</option><option value="Serrador de madeira (serra circular múltipla)
">Serrador de madeira (serra circular múltipla)
</option><option value="Serrador de madeira (serra de fita múltipla)
">Serrador de madeira (serra de fita múltipla)
</option><option value="Serralheiro
">Serralheiro
</option><option value="Servente de obras
">Servente de obras
</option><option value="Subprocurador-geral da república
">Subprocurador-geral da república
</option><option value="Subprocurador-geral do trabalho
">Subprocurador-geral do trabalho
</option><option value="Supervisor de manutenção eletromecânica
">Supervisor de manutenção eletromecânica
</option><option value="Supervisor de manutenção eletromecânica (utilidades)
">Supervisor de manutenção eletromecânica (utilidades)
</option><option value="Supervisor de manutenção eletromecânica industrial, comercial e predial
">Supervisor de manutenção eletromecânica industrial, comercial e predial
</option><option value="Teólogo
">Teólogo
</option><option value="Terapeuta holístico
">Terapeuta holístico
</option><option value="Terapeuta ocupacional
">Terapeuta ocupacional
</option><option value="Tesoureiro de banco
">Tesoureiro de banco
</option><option value="Tingidor de couros e peles
">Tingidor de couros e peles
</option><option value="Tingidor de roupas
">Tingidor de roupas
</option><option value="Tipógrafo
">Tipógrafo
</option><option value="Titeriteiro
">Titeriteiro
</option><option value="Topógrafo
">Topógrafo
</option><option value="Torneiro (lavra de pedra)
">Torneiro (lavra de pedra)
</option><option value="Torneiro na usinagem convencional de madeira
">Torneiro na usinagem convencional de madeira
</option><option value="Torrador de cacau
">Torrador de cacau
</option><option value="Torrador de café
">Torrador de café
</option><option value="Torrista (petróleo)
">Torrista (petróleo)
</option><option value="Tosador de animais domésticos
">Tosador de animais domésticos
</option><option value="Tropeiro
">Tropeiro
</option><option value="Turismólogo
">Turismólogo
</option><option value="Viveirista florestal
">Viveirista florestal
</option><option value="Xaropeiro
">Xaropeiro
</option><option value="Zelador de edifício
">Zelador de edifício
</option><option value="Zootecnista">Zootecnista</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Didn't work. Maybe it don't recognize the php generated code?

Comment: how did you write the code could create plaunker containig your code ! to see

Answer (score 0):

HEAD

```
<head>
    <title>Projeto 02 - Desenvolvimento WEB</title>

    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://kelvin.96.lt/centralizaDivs.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://kelvin.96.lt/style.css">

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://kelvin.96.lt/validadores.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/css/select2.min.css" />
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.min.js"></script>

  </head>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#ocupacoes").select2();

    });
</script>
```

Comment: this method isn't working for me. I guess it is due to incompatibility with php generated code